# DetoxRuntimeError:Detox instance has not been initialized

Tags: ios, testing, expo, detox

Problem Description:

When trying to run the Detox tests for an Expo Ejected App , 
`detox build` is successful, but when trying to run the `detox test`
facing the following error of

> **DetoxRuntimeError:Detox instance has not been initialized**

Steps To reproduce:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of expo-cli by running npm install expo-cli -g
2. Run `expo init` to create a new project
3. cd into your project, run `expo eject` with ExpoKit option
4. run `yarn` && `cd ios && pod install`
5. Follow the steps to configure detox
6. Run expo server `expo start -c`
7. Run `detox build` and `detox test`

Environment:

Detox: 15.4.2
React Native: 0.59.10
Node: v8.11.0
Device: ios simulator, any model
Xcode: 10.3
iOS: 13.3

```
╰─ detox test -l trace -d --debug-synchronization
detox[90083] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="ios.sim.Debug" loglevel="trace" debugSynchronization=3000 reportSpecs=true DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1583325845491 node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 "e2e"
detox[90084] TRACE: [Detox.js/DETOX_CREATE] created a Detox instance with config:
{"deviceConfig":{"binaryPath":"ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app","build":"xcodebuild -workspace ios/example.xcworkspace -scheme example -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build","type":"ios.simulator","device":"iPhone 11 Pro"},"artifactsConfig":{"rootDir":"artifacts/ios.sim.Debug.2020-03-04 12-44-05Z","plugins":{"log":{"enabled":false,"keepOnlyFailedTestsArtifacts":false},"screenshot":{"enabled":true,"shouldTakeAutomaticSnapshots":false,"keepOnlyFailedTestsArtifacts":false},"video":{"enabled":false,"keepOnlyFailedTestsArtifacts":false},"instruments":{"enabled":false,"keepOnlyFailedTestsArtifacts":false},"timeline":{"enabled":false}},"pathBuilder":{"_rootDir":"artifacts/ios.sim.Debug.2020-03-04 12-44-05Z"}}}
detox[90084] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:61975...
detox[90084] DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:61975
detox[90084] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox[90084] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b
detox[90084] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b
detox[90084] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}

detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] applesimutils --list --byType "iPhone 11 Pro"
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #0] [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone 11 Pro",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 11 Pro.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 11 Pro",
    "udid" : "9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269",
    "os" : {
      "buildversion" : "17C45",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "name" : "iOS 13.3",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3",
      "version" : "13.3"
    }
  }
]

detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byId 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 --maxResults 1
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #1] [
  {
    "deviceType" : {
      "name" : "iPhone 11 Pro",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 11 Pro.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro"
    },
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone 11 Pro",
    "udid" : "9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269",
    "os" : {
      "buildversion" : "17C45",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "name" : "iOS 13.3",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3",
      "version" : "13.3"
    }
  }
]

detox[90084] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBootDevice({ coldBoot: false,
  deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  type: 'iPhone 11 Pro' })
detox[90084] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeUninstallApp({ deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.example' })
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #2] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 org.reactjs.native.example.example
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #2] Uninstalling org.reactjs.native.example.example...
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2]
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] org.reactjs.native.example.example uninstalled
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 "/Users/vayu/testReactNative/testExpo/example/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app"
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #3] Installing /Users/vayu/testReactNative/testExpo/example/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app...
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3]
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] /Users/vayu/testReactNative/testExpo/example/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/example.app installed
detox[90084] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeTerminateApp({ deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.example' })
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 org.reactjs.native.example.example
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #4] Terminating org.reactjs.native.example.example...
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4]
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4] org.reactjs.native.example.example terminated
detox[90084] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onTerminateApp({ deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.example' })
detox[90084] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onBeforeLaunchApp({ bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.example',
  deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  launchArgs:
   { detoxServer: 'ws://localhost:61975',
     detoxSessionId: 'e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b' } })
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/vayu/Library/Detox/ios/48f56fb4523932cb5da30a7799afef21908baa16/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 org.reactjs.native.example.example --args -detoxServer "ws://localhost:61975" -detoxSessionId "e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b"
detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #5] Launching org.reactjs.native.example.example...
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #5] org.reactjs.native.example.example: 90123

detox[90084] DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #6] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl get_app_container 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 org.reactjs.native.example.example
detox[90084] TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #6] /Users/vayu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8641A39F-B558-4183-96C4-0F6C587827DF/example.app

detox[90084] INFO:  [AppleSimUtils.js] org.reactjs.native.example.example launched. To watch simulator logs, run:
        /usr/bin/xcrun simctl spawn 9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269 log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate 'process == example'
detox[90123] TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] artifactsManager.onLaunchApp({ bundleId: 'org.reactjs.native.example.example',
  deviceId: '9FD7C5EA-F3B7-4E26-A79E-0A848ADE1269',
  launchArgs:
   { detoxServer: 'ws://localhost:61975',
     detoxSessionId: 'e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b' },
  pid: 90123 })
detox[90084] TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox[90084] TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=isReady (sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b)
detox[90084] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b)
detox[90084] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=testee, sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b
detox[90084] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=testee, sessionId=e6cf1f34-7237-a519-6ccc-2b7996db8f0b
Example: should have welcome screen
Example: should have welcome screen [FAIL]
Example: should show hello screen after tap
Example: should show hello screen after tap [FAIL]
Example: should show world screen after tap
Example: should show world screen after tap [FAIL]

 FAIL  e2e/firstTest.spec.js (300.742s)
  Example
    ✕ should have welcome screen (6ms)
    ✕ should show hello screen after tap (2ms)
    ✕ should show world screen after tap (1ms)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at MissingDetox._defineRequiredProperty (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:8:71)
      at DetoxExportWrapper.(anonymous function).args [as beforeEach] (../node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:53:32)
      at DetoxAdapterImpl.beforeEach (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest/DetoxAdapterImpl.js:17:22)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      1 | describe('Example', () => {
      2 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 3 |     await device.reloadReactNative();
        |           ^
      4 |   });
      5 |
      6 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at device (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee$ (firstTest.spec.js:3:11)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee (firstTest.spec.js:2:14)

  ● Example › should have welcome screen

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

       5 |
       6 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    >  7 |     await expect(element(by.id('welcome'))).toBeVisible();
         |                          ^
       8 |   });
       9 |
      10 |   it('should show hello screen after tap', async () => {

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at by (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee2$ (firstTest.spec.js:7:26)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee2 (firstTest.spec.js:6:36)

  ● Example › should show hello screen after tap

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

  ● Example › should show hello screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at MissingDetox._defineRequiredProperty (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:8:71)
      at DetoxExportWrapper.(anonymous function).args [as beforeEach] (../node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:53:32)
      at DetoxAdapterImpl.beforeEach (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest/DetoxAdapterImpl.js:17:22)

  ● Example › should show hello screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      1 | describe('Example', () => {
      2 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 3 |     await device.reloadReactNative();
        |           ^
      4 |   });
      5 |
      6 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at device (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee$ (firstTest.spec.js:3:11)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee (firstTest.spec.js:2:14)

  ● Example › should show hello screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

       9 |
      10 |   it('should show hello screen after tap', async () => {
    > 11 |     await element(by.id('hello_button')).tap();
         |                   ^
      12 |     await expect(element(by.text('Hello!!!'))).toBeVisible();
      13 |   });
      14 |

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at by (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee3$ (firstTest.spec.js:11:19)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee3 (firstTest.spec.js:10:44)

  ● Example › should show world screen after tap

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

  ● Example › should show world screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at MissingDetox._defineRequiredProperty (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:8:71)
      at DetoxExportWrapper.(anonymous function).args [as beforeEach] (../node_modules/detox/src/DetoxExportWrapper.js:53:32)
      at DetoxAdapterImpl.beforeEach (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest/DetoxAdapterImpl.js:17:22)

  ● Example › should show world screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      1 | describe('Example', () => {
      2 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    > 3 |     await device.reloadReactNative();
        |           ^
      4 |   });
      5 |
      6 |   it('should have welcome screen', async () => {

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at device (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee$ (firstTest.spec.js:3:11)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee (firstTest.spec.js:2:14)

  ● Example › should show world screen after tap

    DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

    HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins

      14 |
      15 |   it('should show world screen after tap', async () => {
    > 16 |     await element(by.id('world_button')).tap();
         |                   ^
      17 |     await expect(element(by.text('World!!!'))).toBeVisible();
      18 |   });
      19 | });

      at MissingDetox.throwError (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:67:11)
      at by (../node_modules/detox/src/utils/MissingDetox.js:46:16)
      at _callee4$ (firstTest.spec.js:16:19)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:16)
      at AsyncIterator.enqueue (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:13)
      at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.async (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:14)
      at Object._callee4 (firstTest.spec.js:15:44)

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

#### my Init.js

```
const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');

// Set the default timeout
jest.setTimeout(120000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

// This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, jest only reports at file-level.
// This is strictly optional.
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
}, 300000);

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am using 'mocha' as a runner & using versions detox: "^15.4.2", mocha: "^7.1.0"

Had this error, for me the cause had been I was trying to console log out an element's text for comparison, outside of an it() function.

```
it('should have Text: A', async () => {
      await expect(element(by.text('A'))).toBeVisible();
});
 >>>> console.log('ELE:: DATE::', element(by.id('TID-datefilter')));
it('should have Text: B', async () => {
      await expect(element(by.text('B'))).toBeVisible();
});
```

Once removed worked fine.

Comment: but @Aron Edwards , i have all my statements inside the it() block and moreover the code gets blocked during the detox initialization itself, where no detox instance is found for the code to move forward

Comment: your `init.js` seems like the one that detox scaffolding provides. I have the same, but with Jest and no `console` statement in my code! But I still get `Async - Callback was not invoked...`